Livewire 3, propiedades condicionales en wire:model
Buen día,
Tengo una aplicación que usa Laravel 10 y Livewire 3, en una vista de un componente livewire tengo lo siguiente:
<x-input.text wire:model.live="editing.referrer.name" id="createReferrer" disabled/>

La propiedad editing está declarada como public User $editing. Los usuarios tienen una relación de uno a uno con un posible referente (Referrer) que en algunos casos contiene apunta a otro usuario (El que refirió al usuario actual) o puede estar vacía, es decir null.
En livewire 2, esta línea en el blade.php muestra correctamente cualquiera de los dos casos, si hay algún referente, entonces muestra su nombere y si no hay referente, es decir null, muestra un input vacío.
En livewire 3 esta línea produce un error en el caso de que el usuario no tenga referente, el error es este:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')

Lo cual ocaciona que no se muestre nada en los otros campos que están relacionados a la propiedad editing. Como el nombre de la persona, su correo, etc...; es decir, todos los input que estén relacionados con algun elemento de la propiedad editing se muestran vacíos.
Intenté ver si usando editing.referrer?.name en wire:model funcionaba, esto corrige el problema en caso de que referrer sea null o contenga datos. Es decir, todos los input siempre muestran los datos de la propiedad editing tenga o no referente. Pero ahora el input:
<x-input.text wire:model.live="editing.referrer?.name" id="createReferrer" disabled/> 

Se muestra vacío siempre, haya referente o no.
¿De qué forma se debería convertir la siguiente línea de livewire 2 para que funcione en la versión 3 y muestre el nombre del referente cuando exista o un campo vacío cuando el referente sea null?
<x-input.text wire:model.live="editing.referrer.name" id="createReferrer" disabled/>

Edición
Encontré una solución alterna. Si utilizo condicionales para ver si el referente existe o no entonces si funciona, pero preferiría encontrar alguna forma de hacerlo en una sola línea como lo tenía en livewire 2 en lugar de esto:
@if ($editing->referrer)
    <x-input.text wire:model.live="editing.referrer.name" id="createReferrer" disabled/>
@else
    <x-input.text value="" id="createReferrer" disabled/>
@endif

